# Create new unique JSON form Existing JSON by filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I want to create new unique JSON form Existing JSON by filter.

I want to following json:

```
var newJson = [
  {"38:1":["40:89","39:86","40:88"]},
  {"38:6":["39:339"]}
]
```

I have following existing json.

```
var existJson = [ 
  {d: "40:89", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "39:86", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "40:88", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "39:339", t: "38:6"}
]
```

I want to create fitter and created new unique JSON like `newJson` 
need to some filter which get unique `t` as key and `d` as array value.

```
{ t : [d1, d2, d3] }
```

Comment: This is usually called "grouping", and is often handled by routines called `groupBy` or something similar. Search for that and you should find lots of solutions. By the way, this is not JSON, it's just regular old JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*`Array.prototype.reduce`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a `hash table` and derive the new json from it - see demo below:

```js
var existJson = [ 
  {d: "40:89", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "39:86", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "40:88", t: "38:1"},
  {d: "39:339", t: "38:6"}
];

// create a hashtable first
var hash = existJson.reduce(function(p,c){
  p[c.t] = p[c.t] || [];
  p[c.t].push(c.d);
  return p;
},{})

// now convert into the required array
var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e){
  let el = {};
  el[e] = hash[e];
  return el;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: the OP wanted `newJson` to be an array of objects, your approach returns a single object

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash (or underscore) groupBy function

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#groupBy

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement:

> I want to following json:
>
> var newJson = [   {"38:1":["40:89","39:86","40:88"]},
>   {"38:6":["39:339"]} ]

Simple solution using `Array.forEach()` and `Array.map()` functions:

```js
var existJson = [
    {d: "40:89", t: "38:1"},
    {d: "39:86", t: "38:1"},
    {d: "40:88", t: "38:1"},
    {d: "39:339", t: "38:6"}
],
    newJson = {};

existJson.forEach(function (o) {
    (this[o.t])? this[o.t].push(o.d) : this[o.t] = [o.d];
}, newJson);

newJson = Object.keys(newJson).map(function (k) {
    var o = {};
    o[k] = newJson[k];
    return o;
});
console.log(newJson);
```